# Flask API function wont work when called by ServerSideProps()

Tags: python, reactjs, api, flask, next.js

I am having an issue with Flask API and Next.js. I have a flask api class function titled "Inbox". The code for this function is shown below.

```html
class Inbox(Resource):
    def get(self):
        try:
            viewed_message_logs = Messages.query.filter(Messages.username==current_user.username).filter(Messages.viewed=='Viewed').all() 
            unviewed_message_logs = Messages.query.filter(Messages.username==current_user.username).filter(Messages.viewed=='Unviewed').all()

            viewed_formatted_messages = [
                {
                    "game": message.game,
                    "body": message.message,
                    "date": message.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                } for message in viewed_message_logs
            ]

            unviewed_formatted_messages = [
                {
                    "game": message.game,
                    "body": message.message,
                    "date": message.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                } for message in unviewed_message_logs
            ]
            

            return {'status':200, 'viewedMessages': viewed_formatted_messages, 'unviewedMessages': unviewed_formatted_messages}
        
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
            return {'status': 400, 'redirect':'/api/test/account', 'message':'There was an error processing the page. Please try your action again or submit a feedback ticket.'}
        
api.add_resource(Inbox, '/api/test/inbox')
```

As you can see, the flask api function uses the flask-login component "current_user". When the next.js function calls this via a client side useEffect, the current_username component is able to grab the users username via "current_user.username". However, I want this information before the page is rendered. So I tried using ServerSideProps() to call the api. When I use this method, I get the following error on the backend.

```html
<flask_login.mixins.AnonymousUserMixin object at 0x7fb1ea4ab970>
```

I immediately know that is a cookies error, and that the session needs to be passed up in order for the current_user functionality to work. However, I have done this on my frontend and it does not work. Here is what my frontend call looks like in next.js.

```html
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {

    // const sessionCookie = await ctx.req.cookies.session

    // console.log(sessionCookie)

    const cookieReq = ctx.req.cookies

    // Parse the session data
    // const parsedCookie = await cookie.parse(sessionCookie)

    // Extract the loggedInUser value from the session data
    // const loggedInUser = parsedCookie.loggedInUser;


    try {
        const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/test/inbox', {
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Content': 'application/json',
                'Cookie': cookieReq,
            }
        })

        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
        }

        const data = await res.json()

        return {
            props: { data }
        }

    } catch (e) {

        console.log(e)

        // return {
        //     redirect: {
        //         destination: '/login',
        //         permanent: false
        //     }
        // }
    }

    return {
        props: {
            cookieReq
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on here? I would assume I am not passing the cookie correctly to be read by current_user. How do I do this. For additional information, I will add my login function that shows how a user is logged in, via the "login_user" functionality. I will also include my flask package versions.

```html
class LoginPage(Resource):
    def post(self):
        args = request.get_json()
        username = args['username']
        password = args['password']
        try:
            if 'loggedInUsername' in session:
                {'redirect':'/api/test/login', 'message':'You are already logged in'}
            else:
                pass

            user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
            if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password):
                login_user(user)
                print('login successful')
                return {'status': '200', 'redirect':'/', 'message':'You have been logged in!'}
            else:
                print('login unsuccessful')
                return {'status': '400','redirect' : '/login', 'message':'We do not recognize an account with that email and password. Please try again.'}
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
            print('Exception reached at login, line 268')
            flash('There was an unexpected error. Please try your action again.', 'danger')
            return {'redirect':'/api/test/login', 'message':'There was an error. Please try again'}

api.add_resource(LoginPage, '/api/test/login')
```

My packaging is:

```html
Flask==2.0.0
Flask-Bcrypt==1.0.1
Flask-Login==0.6.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Session==0.4.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
Flask-WTF==1.0.1
```